# MySQL Cluster MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations and RAM

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-cluster

Why increasing of `MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations` lead to higher consumption of RAM?

I need high value for fast filling tables with some random data, but i noticed that my datanodes are swapping at starting with high values (5,000,000 - 10,000,000).

There is another way to solve it: use innodb then alter table, but there might be other difficulties (some people complain about "lock wait timeout exceeded").

I just want to know how it working and how number of operations tied with RAM.

Comment: This is a good summary: http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-cluster-memory-sizing Most memory buffers are preallocated in memory to avoid latency issues when reserving huge chunks of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good summary: http://fromdual.com/mysql-cluster-memory-sizing

Most memory buffers are preallocated in memory to avoid latency issues when reserving huge chunks of memory.